# How do I get event information on all calendars with Microsoft Graph Explorer?

Tags: get, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar, outlook-calendar

I want to get attendees and subjects from all calendar events with Microsoft Graph Explorer. I also want to see which calendar these events belong to.
I tried this:

```
GET => https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events$select=subject,attendees,calendar
```

And I can get event subjects and attendees, but I can't get the calendar names in the same response. How should I write a query on Microsoft Graph Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PidTagParentDisplay property of the folder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagparentdisplay-canonical-property which you request as a singleValueExtendedProperties like

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$select=subject,attendees,calendar&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'String%200x0E05')
```

and you should then get back the name of the calendar in the response eg

```html
            "singleValueExtendedProperties@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('7bedfe35-1780-4c50-8eca-50b0a37eb470')/events('AAMkADVmMTU2OGIxLWUxOTAtNDQzNi05ZWY1LWU3MWQxMGY1NTE5ZgBGAAAAAAA11iv2WTcWSb1HvIjYVgS9BwC753HH1GDaQ4zC-BDnxVlLAAAAAAENAAC753HH1GDaQ4zC-BDnxVlLAADuMzUuAAA%3D')/singleValueExtendedProperties",
            "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
                {
                    "id": "String 0xe05",
                    "value": "Calendar"
                }
            ]
```